# Play SecureSocial customization

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I just downloaded the SecureSocial plugin and installed it.
I have a webapp build using Play framework 2.1 in Java.
Now I don't how how to customize this module.
If I click on register I have a page asking me for the email and then I get to another screen asking me my name, email, password.
In all examples using SecureSocial  there is not this kind of screen.
[image]

This is what i have in my play.plugins :

> 1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
>   9994:securesocial.core.DefaultAuthenticatorStore
>   9995:securesocial.core.DefaultIdGenerator
>   9996:securesocial.core.providers.utils.DefaultPasswordValidator
>   9997:securesocial.controllers.DefaultTemplatesPlugin
>   9998:service.InMemoryUserService
>   9999:securesocial.core.providers.utils.BCryptPasswordHasher
>   10004:securesocial.core.providers.UsernamePasswordProvider

How can I get rid if this screen ?
I was looking for some examples in Java but I did not found.
What I've read is that I need to get the source of the module and modify them. All I've found is the scala sources.

Can anyone help me get start understanding this module?

Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 4):

Two things to answer your question:

1. If you wish to customize the Secure Social default views (screens), just read the doc: http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html That's easy to do.
2. If you wish to change the default behaviour of the module, then I don't think it is possible, without editing and modifying the source code of SecureSocial. But just keep something in mind: SecureSocial is a social authentication module, so its main interest is to use the social networks to login. The standard username/password authentication is just a special case of an intern authentication provider (other providers are Google, Facebook, Twitter, ...).

Hope this helps

Comment: 1. Are you kidding ? Of course I've read that doc but there is so little information ...                                                  2.                                             OK, I got it. Thanks

Comment: No kidding at all. First have a look at the source files (ex: the Login page is here https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/views/login.scala.html). You might copy-paste it and then adapt it to your own view. Then create your own TemplatesPlugin as described in the doc. Finally, just use the view you created in your TemplatesPlugin, like this   `override def getLoginPage[A](implicit request: Request[A], form: Form[(String, String)],
                               msg: Option[String] = None): Html =
  {
    views.custom.html.login(form, msg)
  }`